# Why doesn't the widgets color change when the appearance mode function is called?

Tags: python, class, customtkinter

The overall appearance changes to dark mode when the function is called when i press the button, but all the widgets still has the same color as if the light mode was still on.

```
import customtkinter

class App(customtkinter.CTk):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.geometry("1000x600")

    self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="press me", fg_color=("red", "green") ,command = lambda: self.set_appearance_mode("dark"))
    self.button.pack()
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

When i run the code outside of a class it's working, but whenever i put the code inside of a class it's not working anymore, as shown below.

```
import customtkinter

window = customtkinter.CTk()
window.geometry("1000x600")

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(window, text="press me", fg_color=("red", "green") ,command = lambda: customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark"))
button.pack()

window.mainloop()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command needs to stay like this:

```py
command = lambda: customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
```

Because you're not calling the `set_appearance_mode` method on the `App` class but still on the customtkinter library instance.